# How to create this widget ('image is mentioned below') in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzKjz.png , kindly visit this url to check the widget i want to design

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/bubble
please check this package|~

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are searching for is a `tooltip` (my best guess from the image you provided) flutter has a `tooltip` package inbuilt in `material.dart`

you can see here how it is implemented easily

```
Tooltip(  
    message: 'User Account',  
    child: IconButton(  
    icon: Icon(Icons.high_quality),  
    onPressed: () {  
    /* your code */  
    },  
  ),  
),
```

for more you can visit [here](https://www.javatpoint.com/flutter-tooltip)

Comment: Thanks , Lets me share the complete screen with you , tool tip pops up but i need it all time . I have marked the widget http://i.imgur.com/0gFAlBZ.png

Comment: @TusharNagar
There is a Duration property inside this widget you can set it for a longer duration
you can refer to this link : [link](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Tooltip-class.html)